# Using Ktor with JWT RS256 for authentication leads to illegal base64 char exception

Tags: kotlin, jwt, ktor

I am trying to implement authentication in my Ktor server using JWT, and specifically, using RS256 signing.

I was following the [official documentation](https://ktor.io/docs/jwt.html#configure-jwt) and the [sample project](https://github.com/ktorio/ktor-documentation/blob/1.6.8/codeSnippets/snippets/auth-jwt-rs256/src/main/kotlin/com/example/Application.kt) but I've stumbled upon an `500: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal base64 character 2b` error that I cannot figure out.

Here is my HOCON config with a sample private key:

```
ktor {
  development = true
  deployment {
    port = 8080
    port = ${?PORT}
    autoreload = true
    watch = [backend]
  }
  application {
    modules = [app.company.ApplicationKt.module]
  }
}

jwt {
  privateKey = "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"
  issuer = "http://0.0.0.0:8080/"
  audience = "http://0.0.0.0:8080/login"
  realm = "Company Login"
}

postgres {
  url = ${pg_url}
  user = ${pg_username}
  password = ${pg_password}
}
```

my configure security module:

```
fun Application.configureSecurity() {
    val jwtAudience = environment.config.property("jwt.audience").getString()
    val jwtIssuer = environment.config.property("jwt.issuer").getString()
    val jwtRealm = environment.config.property("jwt.realm").getString()
    val jwtPK = environment.config.property("jwt.privateKey").getString()
    val jwkProvider = JwkProviderBuilder(jwtIssuer)
        .cached(10, 24, TimeUnit.HOURS)
        .rateLimited(10, 1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
        .build()
    install(Authentication) {
        jwt("auth-jwt") {
            realm = jwtRealm
            verifier(jwkProvider, jwtIssuer) {
                acceptLeeway(3)
            }
            validate { credential ->
                if (credential.payload.getClaim("username").asString() != "") {
                    JWTPrincipal(credential.payload)
                } else {
                    null
                }
            }
            challenge { _, _ ->
                call.respond(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, "Token is not valid or has expired")
            }
        }
    }

    routing {
        post("/login") {

            val userCredentials = call.receive<UserLoginCredentials>()

            //todo check credentials
            if (userCredentials.username != "mike" || userCredentials.password != "shh") {
                call.respond(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, "Credentials do not match.")
                return@post
            }

            val publicKey = jwkProvider.get("6f8856ed-9189-488f-9011-0ff4b6c08edc").publicKey
            val keySpecPKCS8 = PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(Base64.getDecoder().decode(jwtPK))
            val privateKey = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA").generatePrivate(keySpecPKCS8)
            val token = JWT.create()
                .withAudience(jwtAudience)
                .withIssuer(jwtIssuer)
                .withClaim("username", userCredentials.username)
                .withExpiresAt(Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 60000))
                .sign(Algorithm.RSA256(publicKey as RSAPublicKey, privateKey as RSAPrivateKey))
            call.respond(hashMapOf("token" to token))
        }
        authenticate("auth-jwt") {
            get("/hello") {
                val principal = call.principal<JWTPrincipal>()
                val username = principal!!.payload.getClaim("username").asString()
                val expiresAt = principal.expiresAt?.time?.minus(System.currentTimeMillis())
                call.respondText("Hello, $username! Token is expired at $expiresAt ms.")
            }
        }
        staticFiles(".well-known/jwks.json", File("certs/jwks.json"))
    }
}
```

And finally, the `certs/jwks.json`:

```
{
  "keys": [
    {
      "kty": "RSA",
      "e": "65537",
      "kid": "6f8856ed-9189-488f-9011-0ff4b6c08edc",
      "n":"MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAuYAHLNnQXSGiKS2MY4u14Pzi3Ckk2FOwghFvcE2EP9Br7pTJ4j5HDYQ7vT+LHj6N2chnhGvTxZrj2+ty5fakPyGXNsC5UEMEUfTcyWe1dN2JidRLLBsUV3CvlmGdPPVLODrQQm7TMVA5x2Rwq9w9OiuD9KMF79Z87T6l7JfM9lXG+TM+JjR1pD25bMm8pCzb5+VKXEsBYwgXMPVIZ4mSm/07daiXmsfj7XDNP6U1B5xltZSdb3ZFiNYLrZNZHvsO+Q2shma9UwqRLqr/Fqx4oNggbLLqut4BujLj/Gq76E4LgwYUqdx7hVOMjZGt9E5tyFMWPRJ1SyK37zXeYxSRcwIDAQAB"
    }
  ]
}
```

The key pair was generated using `openssl genpkey -algorithm RSA -out private_key.pem -aes256`. When I make a POST request to the /login endpoint (sending the "mike", "shh" payload), I get the illegal char error. Debugging the server seems to point to the `val publicKey = jwkProvider.get("6f8856ed-9189-488f-9011-0ff4b6c08edc").publicKey` which I don't get. What am I missing?

**Update:** Alright, I have generated new key-pairs using `ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "email"`, then converted them to pem files using `ssh-keygen -f ktor.pub -e -m pem > ktor.pub.pem` for the public key and `ssh-keygen -p -m PEM -f ktor` for the private one. I then removed any new lines and converted them to the Base64URL encoding. I also encoded the exponent ("e") using `openssl rsa -pubin -in ktor.pub.pem -text -noout | grep "Exponent" | awk '{prin t $2}'` and updated the fields in the project. Now, when I debug the call, the exception seems to be `500: java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: java.security.InvalidKeyException: invalid key format` caused by this function call `val publicKey = jwkProvider.get("6f8856ed-9189-488f-9011-0ff4b6c08edc").publicKey`, specifically the `publicKey = kf.generatePublic(new RSAPublicKeySpec(modulus, exponent));` in:

```
public PublicKey getPublicKey() throws InvalidPublicKeyException {
    PublicKey publicKey = null;

    switch (type) {
        case ALGORITHM_RSA:
            try {
                KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance(ALGORITHM_RSA);
                BigInteger modulus = new BigInteger(1, Base64.getUrlDecoder().decode(stringValue("n")));
                BigInteger exponent = new BigInteger(1, Base64.getUrlDecoder().decode(stringValue("e")));
                publicKey = kf.generatePublic(new RSAPublicKeySpec(modulus, exponent));
            } catch (InvalidKeySpecException e) {
                throw new InvalidPublicKeyException("Invalid public key", e);
            } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
                throw new InvalidPublicKeyException("Invalid algorithm to generate key", e);
            }
            break;
```

Comment: The key data in a [JWK](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7517.html#section-3) is Base64URL encoded (which is a little bit different from Base64. The *Illegal base64 character 2b* is a '+' sign, which is one of the differences between the two encodings. Base64URL uses '+' instead of '-' and '_' instead of '/'.  As I'm not working with Kotlin and don't know that JWT framework, I can't really tell you how to solve it.

Comment: Seems like the value for the `n` key in the `jwks.json` isn't base64 **URL** encoded. The following line of code throws the exception: `Base64.getUrlDecoder().decode(stringValue("n"))`

Comment: @AlekseiTirman I don't know what exception you got, but the `n` value in the JWK is Base64URL encoded. The error which the OP got comes from an attempt somewhere in the code to decode it as Base64 (instead of Base64URL).

Comment: As he pointed out correctly, the exception comes from the `jwkProvider.get("6f8856ed-9189-488f-9011-0ff4b6c08edc").publicKey` line, which calls `Base64.getUrlDecoder().decode(stringValue("n"))` and that leads to the exception. You can try running it by yourself to make sure.

Comment: @AlekseiTirman I'm sorry, my mistake. You're right. The key *should be* Base64URL encoded (containing `-` and `_`), but is actually Base64 encoded (`+`and `/`), and the `+` (2b) caused the error. I think the error message *Illegal base64 character 2b* confused me. Actually 2b is a legal Base64 character, but illegal in Base64URL.

Comment: @jps I have updated my post with some new data after making sure I'm using Base64URL encoding.

Comment: My comment regarding Base64URL referred only to the JWK (the public key), not the PEM file with the private key.  `e` should now be `AQAB` and `n` similar to the one shown above, just with `-` and `_` instead of `+`and `/`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Preliminarily, the value you posted for privatekey is clearly fake (which is fine, you don't want to publicize a real privatekey), but the result of `ssh-keygen (mod) -mPEM` is NOT PKCS8 and not correct for use in standard Java crypto i.e. `PKCS8EncodedKeySpec`. OTOH the result of `ssh-keygen (mod) -mPKCS8` (with empty password) is, and so is the output from `openssl genpkey` with no cipher or in 3.0 up `openssl genrsa` ditto, or `openssl pkey` with no cipher and input in traditional *or* PKCS8 format.

[JWK for RSA publickey](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7518#section-6.3.1) must have e the exponent in base64url (not in decimal as you have) and n the modulus in base64url not the entire X.509/PKIX SPKI structure in base64 as you have (apparently from an OpenSSL-format publickey file, which OpenSSH `ssh-keygen` weirdly calls `-mPKCS8` NOT `-mPEM`).

The example code you reference (I link the current version instead, but it doesn't appear to have changed) has the publickey JWK in https://github.com/ktorio/ktor-documentation/blob/2.3.7/codeSnippets/snippets/auth-jwt-rs256/certs/jwks.json corresponding to the privatekey in https://github.com/ktorio/ktor-documentation/blob/2.3.7/codeSnippets/snippets/auth-jwt-rs256/src/main/resources/application.conf -- which is in base64 PKCS8-clear, thus usable after decoding in Java crypto PKCS8EncodedKeySpec. But AFAICS none of the relevant ktor documentation tells you how to create this. If you have OpenSSL on Unix (including almost-Unix like WSL or git4win) you can do

```
$ echo >77770123.pk8 MIIBVQIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCAT8wggE7AgEAAkEAtfJaLrzXILUg1U3N1KV8yJr92GHn5OtYZR7qWk1Mc4cy4JGjklYup7weMjBD9f3bBVoIsiUVX6xNcYIr0Ie0AQIDAQABAkEAg+FBquToDeYcAWBe1EaLVyC45HG60zwfG1S4S3IB+y4INz1FHuZppDjBh09jptQNd+kSMlG1LkAc/3znKTPJ7QIhANpyB0OfTK44lpH4ScJmCxjZV52mIrQcmnS3QzkxWQCDAiEA1Tn7qyoh+0rOO/9vJHP8U/beo51SiQMw0880a1UaiisCIQDNwY46EbhGeiLJR1cidr+JHl86rRwPDsolmeEF5AdzRQIgK3KXL3d0WSoS//K6iOkBX3KMRzaFXNnDl0U/XyeGMuUCIHaXv+n+Brz5BDnRbWS+2vkgIe9bUNlkiArpjWvX+2we
$ # this is the value from the ktor example; alternatively use body part from
$ # openssl genpkey -algorithm rsa or ssh-keygen (gen/mod) -mPKCS8 
$ base64 -d <77770123.pk8 | openssl pkey -inform der -pubout | tee 77770123.spki
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MFwwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADSwAwSAJBALXyWi681yC1INVNzdSlfMia/dhh5+Tr
WGUe6lpNTHOHMuCRo5JWLqe8HjIwQ/X92wVaCLIlFV+sTXGCK9CHtAECAwEAAQ==
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
$ # or substitute here the file from `ssh-keygen -e -mPKCS8` for your key

$ openssl pkey -in 77770123.spki -pubin -noout -text
RSA Public-Key: (512 bit)
Modulus:
    00:b5:f2:5a:2e:bc:d7:20:b5:20:d5:4d:cd:d4:a5:
    7c:c8:9a:fd:d8:61:e7:e4:eb:58:65:1e:ea:5a:4d:
    4c:73:87:32:e0:91:a3:92:56:2e:a7:bc:1e:32:30:
    43:f5:fd:db:05:5a:08:b2:25:15:5f:ac:4d:71:82:
    2b:d0:87:b4:01
Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
$ # 512-bit! that's totally insecure. Use that ONLY as an example!

$ echo 010001 | xxd -p -r | base64 # note even number of hex digits
AQAB
$ # this particular base64 is already base64url and doesn't need tr
$ # in practice nowadays everything uses e=F4 (decimal 65537, hex 010001, base64 AQAB) 
$ # so you _could_ hardcode this, but I show the proper method anyway

$ echo "b5:f2:5a:2e:bc:d7:20:b5:20:d5:4d:cd:d4:a5:
    7c:c8:9a:fd:d8:61:e7:e4:eb:58:65:1e:ea:5a:4d:
    4c:73:87:32:e0:91:a3:92:56:2e:a7:bc:1e:32:30:
    43:f5:fd:db:05:5a:08:b2:25:15:5f:ac:4d:71:82:
    2b:d0:87:b4:01" | tr -d ": \n" | xxd -p -r | base64 | tr +/ -_ | tr -d "=\n"
tfJaLrzXILUg1U3N1KV8yJr92GHn5OtYZR7qWk1Mc4cy4JGjklYup7weMjBD9f3bBVoIsiUVX6xNcYIr0Ie0AQ
$ # note leading 00 byte omitted; that's an artifact of the ASN.1 encoding
```

Comment: This is an excellent write-up, thank you so much for the detailed answer. I got completely lost with the process of generating the keys and how to encode them properly. This put me on the right track and now everything works smoothly!